# Take "setFrom" name as in Gmail configuration using Swift Mailer

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using Swiftmailer to send emails in Symfony project.

```
$msg = (new \Swift_Message("Subject"))
            ->setFrom('xxx123@gmail.com')
            ->setTo('yyy@gmail.com')
            ->setBody($mailContent);
```

In the received email, the name of Sender looks like **xxx123**. But the name for this email id in its configuration is **XXX YYY**.

I can use,

```
->setFrom('xxx123@gmail.com' => 'XXX YYY')
```

but, I don't want to set name directly in the code as it may be changed to something else like **YYY ZZZ**.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Add variable ->setFrom(['xxx123@gmail.com' => $fromName])

Comment: Do you want to use sender name from config file like `parameters.yml`? Or what do you want?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov I want to use name of account for the provided email.

Comment: Who provided it and where? Sender name is ALWAYS set in the header of every message. So header can be set by any email client. Your email server can rewrite header but in specific cases like Gmail rewrite all email addresses that you didn't validate in the account settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sender name is always set in the header of every message. So header can be set by any email client. Your SwiftMailer is also email client in this case.

Your email server can rewrite header but only in specific cases. Like Gmail rewrite all email addresses that you didn't validate in the account settings to your base email.

If you need to fetch your sender name from Gmail account you can use Gmail-API. Authenticate your application with OAuth and send GET request to url:

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/sendAs/YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS

You will receive JSON like this:

```
{
 "sendAsEmail": "YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS",
 "displayName": "SENDER NAME THAT YOU NEED",
 "replyToAddress": "",
 "signature": "Your standard signature for emails created by Gmail in browser",
 "isPrimary": true,
 "isDefault": true
}
```

More about Google API for this request you can find here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/get

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$fromEmail = "xxx123@gmail.com";
$fromName = "Sender Name";

$msg = (new \Swift_Message("Subject"))
        ->setFrom([$fromEmail => $fromName])
        ->setTo('yyy@gmail.com')
        ->setBody($mailContent);
```

If you put only email, code will cut name from email until @. In your case it's: **xxx123**@gmail.com

Comment: Is it possible to not declare $fromName and use actual name of Email account?

Comment: @VinothKumar if you're using SMPT - than you may not set function setFrom. It will automatically. Documentation https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html#the-smtp-transport

Comment: I'm using SMPT but couldn't send the mail when setFrom() is not given.